# creating valid json data in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

When a new User is created, I save the username and password (no hashed) in a json file as well as in the DB, so every time I'm appending new users to the json file:

```
{
  "user3": "demo"
} {
  "user4": "demo"
} {
  "user4": "demo"
} {
  "user5": "demo"
}
```

the code:

```
$data = array($request->input('username') => $request->input('password'));
            $datos = json_encode($data);
            File::append(storage_path('archivos/datos.json'), $data);
```

of course the format above isn't valid json, how could i get this

```
[{
"user3": "demo"
}, {
"user4": "demo"
}, {
"user4": "demo"
}, {
"user5": "demo"
}, {
"user5": "demo"
}, {
"user5": "demo"
}, {
"user7": "demo"
 }, {
"user8": "demo"
 }]
```

and read it using foreach like this:

```
$result = File::get(storage_path('archivos/datos.json'));
$result = json_decode($result);
foreach($result as $key=>$item){
   echo $key .''. $item;
}
```

Comment: If you want to append to a JSON array in a file, you'll need to decode and re-encode it each time.

Comment: should i use array_push then?

Comment: Also, may I STRONGLY suggest not to store plain-text passwords?

Answer (score 1):

First get the string from file then you can do a str_replace all `"} {"` with `"} , {"` a json also have `[` at the start and `]` at the end so we add them too:

```
$json = "[".str_replace('} {', '},{', $fileContent)."]";
```

Here we have a json string in $json variable so we can convert it to array by this:

```
$users = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem he needs to solve. The OP's first code snippet, which you're addressing here, was just an example of the results of his current attempt.

Comment: What I think he want is get none json string from a file as json it's not possible, Also every time reading the file decoding and adding new user to the array then writing this in file it's not a good idea because for every user we have to do this it's not good for performance

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way would be to append some data:

```
fopen('myfile.json', 'a');
```

but you want to store an array, so you have to read the content of the file, update it and save it.

```
$users = json_decode(file_get_content(storage_path('archivos/datos.json')));

$users[] = $newUser;

file_put_contents(storage_path('archivos/datos.json'), json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

you can also make a one-liner (ugly, but works):

```
file_put_contents(storage_path('archivos/datos.json'), json_encode(json_decode(file_get_content(storage_path('archivos/datos.json')))[] = $newUser, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```